# CS-Cart/Smarty How to strip Image Tags from Product Thumbnails?

Tags: smarty, cs-cart

I'm trying to strip the image tags from the CS Cart List Thumb,

```
{include file="common/image.tpl" image_width="400px" image_height="400px" images=$product.main_pair obj_id=$obj_id_prefix no_ids=true class="ty-thumbnail-list__img|strip_tags"}
```

Does anyone have any idea why that strip_tags isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you're trying to do, but in any case, you put `strip_tags` in a wrong place

strip_tags is a modifier for a variable or a string and it works like this:

```
{$variable|strip_tags}
{'My <b>text</b>'|strip_tags}
```

You're just passing it as a name of a class. Please, read more about how strip_tags works [here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.strip.tags.tpl)

Comment: I have used the same method, however I have found that sometimes I want to remove the image but have wanted to other styling options of text for instance. Is there a more precise modifier to remove only the image but keep text styling